# Ubuntu loading but not opening applications

Tags: 18.04

I am running a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 with windows and occasionally when I open an application it'll load in the top left corner but when it stops loading it doesn't open. When it starts doing this it will do the same for every application including things like settings, terminal, text editor, ECT... It usually requires either sitting idle for 15+ minutes or a restart to fix temporarily.

Does anyone know what this problem is and/or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jonathan How much RAM do you have? Can you try entering the command `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a` when the issue happens the next time?

Comment: I'm suspecting a faulty disk. Can you keep a terminal window open running "dmesg -w" and look at the output when this happens? If there's a defective disk, you'll see a bunch of lines in red reporting input/output errors, connection resets etc. on /dev/sd(something)